# Java reflection framework and security

Tags: java, reflection

Assume I have a singleton class in an external lib to my application. But still I can 
create instances of that particular class using reflection. Like this

```
    Class clas = Class.forName(Private.class.getName());

    for(Constructor c : clas.getDeclaredConstructors()){
        c.setAccessible(true);
        Private p = (Private) c.newInstance();
        System.out.println(p);
    }
```

How can I restrict this ? .

Thanks
J

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481862/how-to-limit-setaccessible-to-only-legitimate-uses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using a [SecurityManager](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) and controlling controlling `ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks")` ([example](http://javabeans.asia/2008/10/12/how_to_set_securitymanager_and_java_security_policy_programmatically.html)).

The security manager impacts performances though, and it is rarely used on the server side.

Comment: [How big is the performance impact?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903423/security-manager-rarely-used-on-server)

Answer (score 1):

See [Hack any Java class using reflection attack](http://javabeans.asia/2008/10/13/hack_any_java_class_using_reflection_attack.html) and 
[How to set SecurityManager and Java security policy programmatically](http://javabeans.asia/2008/10/12/how_to_set_securitymanager_and_java_security_policy_programmatically.html) .

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about singletons in particular: that's one reason why the best way to implement them is via an enum:

```
public enum YourSingleton {
    INSTANCE;
    // methods go here
}
```

If you're talking about using `setAccessible()` in general: If the code is written by someone you don't trust not to do underhanded tricks like that, you shouldn't run it anyway (or run it in a sandbox). Among developers, public/private should be considered metainformation about how the code is intended to be used - not as a security feature.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: **you can't**.

Any constructor, public as well as private, can be accessed by reflection and can be used to instantiate a new object.

You will need to resort to other methods such as [`SecurityManager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can restrict this.

It is obviously a dangerous/questionable practice to use reflection to access the private parts of others (*snicker*), but it is sometimes necessary by various types of tools and applications.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is sort of metaprogramming and therefore requires check on different layer of abstraction. From Javadoc I suppose, you should use SecurityManager to enforce the behaviour you want: [setAccessible()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/).
Generally IMHO you should really know what you are doing when you are metaprogramming and changing access should really have good reasons to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
private static final Private INSTANCE = new Private();
    private Private() {
        if(INSTANCE !=null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already instantiated");
    }
     public static Private getInstance() {
            return INSTANCE;
        }
```

Comment: The singleton is outside of his reach in a third party jar. So this won't help at all. This technique is by the way not safe, as you can change it via reflection (as mentioned in the question).