# Hiding my security key from java reflection

Tags: java, security, reflection

The below class is my security key provider for encryption.

```
public class MySecretKey {
private String key="2sfdsdf7787fgrtdfg#$%@cj5";
...
//Some Util methods goes on  Here .
}
```

First I didn't belive that one can access the  `private`  data without a getter, but, My goodness, I am able to see the key in the console now .

And  somewhere else using reflection we can see the code  like below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Stacker myClass = new Stacker();
        Field key= myClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("key");
        field1.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(key.get(myClass));
    }
```

How can I hide my key from outside my class :( ,even `private` keyword also not helping me in case of Reflection.

Please give me some hint .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java reflection framework and security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652632/java-reflection-framework-and-security)

Comment: Your key would be available in the compiled code anyways...

Comment: Yup.  There's no way to keep data compiled into your code like that secure.  Step one of the proper solution, however, is _not to compile your code together with untrusted code._

Comment: I thought of the encryption key as just one _example_ of a private field that can be accessed with reflection and setAccesible(true).  There have been a few cases where I subclassed a library class, but I needed access to the superclass's private field for proper execution, e.g. a HashMap, so I used this reflection trick.  Of course encryption keys should never reside in code, but I think that there are other cases where this trick merely breaks encapsulation, not security.  In short, this question is about preventing the reflection trick, not securing an encryption key. +1

Comment: I think, in general, information hiding (using private/protected/etc. members) is a trick to help prevent bugs and to help prevent poor code design; not as a security measure. I.e. it might stop bad (as in foolish) code from being written, not bad (as in malicious) code from being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setAccessible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject%5b%5d,%20boolean%29) says

> First, if there is a security manager, its checkPermission method is called with a `ReflectPermission("suppressAccessChecks")` permission.

so you can prevent this by denying the *suppressAccessChecks* permission.

Really though, it'd be better to avoid relying on the JVM to preserve object inviolability.  [Joe-E](http://code.google.com/p/joe-e/) allows for mutual-suspicion between classes within a JVM, but the JVM wasn't designed for that.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred solution is to store the key in a file, and then use file system permissions to restrict access to the file.  It's not a perfect solution (certainly not as convenient) but it's better than hardwiring the key in the code.

Answer (score 1):

All the strings defined in a Java class can be easily inspected by opening the class file in a hexadecimal editor, they're not, by any means, hidden. not to mention that they can be retrieved programatically using reflection, as you just discovered.

The mechanism you're using for "hiding" a private key is broken, and utterly flawed. You should instead store the key in an external file, for example a serialized, encrypted key store, protected by other means - for example, a password or another key stored elsewhere.

Comment: This is a good point, but object inviolability is still relied on to protect one-time secrets obtained from a `SecureRandom` after class load.  I don't think the OP excludes that use case.

Comment: This is just moving the problem forward... where do you hide the password used to uncipher the private key holder ?

Answer (score 1):

Easy,
Make this class `non-instantiatable` 
How?

Make a private constructor and make your `key` field `static`

So your class will look like this

```
public class MySecretKey {
    public static String key="2sfdsdf7787fgrtdfg#$%@cj5";
    private MySecretKey(){} //Private constructor
    //No Util methods will go here.
}
```