# Security manager rarely used on server?

Tags: java, securitymanager

A recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903318/how-to-prevent-accessing-private-variable-from-java-reflection) on SO lead me to an older [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2652651/18573) about the Java Security Manager. My question about this line in that answer:

> The security manager impacts performances though, and it is rarely used on the server side.

Can someone please back this up or refute? I thought there is *always* a security manager, a custom one or the default and that containers use it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

In server-side code that *you* yourself write, I can't think for any need for you to use a SecurityManager, since if you are writing the code to perform some operation in *your* application, it's unlikely that you need to check if your code has the permissions that you have given it.

For instance, a lot of the methods in SecurityManager are related to IO operations - `checkDelete()`, `checkRead()`, `checkWrite()`, etc. The JDK library classes will call these methods when you try to create/write/read/delete a file, so calling them yourself would be pointless.

So it's unlikely that your server-side code would make much use of the SecurityManager. However, the code that your code runs in - if you are deployed in a servlet container for instance - might make use of these methods, because they are interested in determining if *your* code has some level of permission that *they* give it.

Comment: If I understand you right, you mean that the top level container on server *will* use a `SecurityManager` to implement security policies on (arbitrary) content deployed to it but there is no need to use on in the individual deployed units themselves. Correct?

Comment: Yes, at least I cannot think of a need. A administrator of Tomcat, for instance, might set certain permissions as to what the contained web applications can do.