# About local final variables in Java

Tags: java, final, inner-classes

In java Program, parameters which is defined as `String` in method declaration. But in method definition it is accessed as `final String` variable. Whether it'll lead to some issues (like security, memory problem)?

For Example:

**Method Declaration**

```
join(String a,String b);
```

**Method definition**

```
public void join(final String a,final String b)
{
    Authenticator au = new Authenticator(){
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
        return new PasswordAuthentication(a,b)}
    };
}
```

Please help for me and clarify my doubts. Thanks in advance

P.S. I'm accessing a and b as final variable because I've got to use it in the inner class.

Comment: Why is this tagged "outofmemoryerror"? Are you getting a memory error? Please expand on your problem, it's a bit difficult to understand.

Comment: @Satish: can you clarify what your doubts are? I want to make sure that I've addressed every concerns.

Comment: @Satish: also, just to make sure, you are aware that Java passes by value and does not have pass by reference, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: @polygenelubricants: in Method definition i forced to use this variable as final.So i'm having fear whether it'll lead to some run time problem and performance issues.i'm novice in java. when variable is declared as final, how it helps for free up memory at the end of the method

Comment: @Sathish: garbage collectibility is defined in terms of whether or not there are live references to the object. Local variables and method arguments go out of scope at the end of the method (or the block they're declared in), regardless of whether or not they're `final`. Going out of scope means the reference is "dead". The object itself may still have live references from elsewhere.

Comment: @polygenelubricants:Thanks for answer.Without final variable when i change above example as
class a{
public void join(final String a,final String b)
{
    joinauth au = new Authenticator(a,b);
......
}
private class joinauth extends Authenticator {
    String a = null;
    String b = null;
    public joinauth (String a, String b) {
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
    }
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      return new PasswordAuthentication(this.a, this.b);
    }
  }
}
Which one is better when analysed according to the performance,memory.

Comment: @Sathish: I'd say the local-variable-only version is better, because unlike the field version, the local variable goes out of scope once the method finishes. The field version hangs on to the string objects for as long as the `joinauth` instance is live. Like I said, it's really not about `final` or not, but rather how many live references are there to the object for garbage collectibility.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`final` simply means that the reference/primitive variable can not be assigned a new value. It's not the same as `const` concept (which Java doesn't have); it does *NOT* guarantee immutability. `String` in Java, of course, is already immutable enough (barring nasty reflection attacks).

Using `final` modifier for parameter arguments will have no effect on security or garbage collection. It's done for readability and to enforce coding convention that parameter variables aren't being reused in the method to store other values.

Upon encountering a `final` modifier, a human reader can be assured that the value of this variable, once assigned, will not change within its scope. The compiler would enforce this behavior, and would not compile a program that illegally tries to assign a new value to variable that is declared `final`.

> #### [JLS 14.2.4 `final` Variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.4)
>
> A variable can be declared `final`. A `final` variable may only be assigned to once. It is a compile time error if a `final` variable is assigned to unless it is definitely unassigned immediately prior to the assignment.

As mentioned, however, `final` does not in itself guarantee immutability of the object being referred to. A `final StringBuilder sb` declaration guarantees that `sb`, once assigned and within its scope, will not refer to another `StringBuilder` instance. `StringBuilder` itself, of course, is a mutable object.

---

#### `final` and inner classes

Another use of `final` modifier is to allow local variables etc to be used by an inner class:

> #### [JLS 8.1.3 Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.3)
>
> Any local variable, formal method parameter or exception handler parameter used but not declared in an inner class must be declared `final`.

This has to do with how inner classes using these variables are compiled in Java, an implementation detail that perhaps is not all too relevant for the discussion. Essentially, the values of these `final` variables are given to the inner classes at construction time. Subsequent changes to the local variables (if allowed) would not be seen by the inner class instance. To ensure proper semantics, these local variables must thus be declared `final`.

---

#### Effects of `final` modifier for local variables at run-time

`final` modifier for local variables/formal method parameters is a compile-time concept, and is not present at, say, the bytecode level (i.e. it plays a very different role than `final` modifier for fields, classes and methods). Thus, this concept simply doesn't exist at run-time, where `final` and non-`final` local variables are indistinguishable; the usage of the keyword itself would not have any effect on garbage collectibility and/or performance.

Garbage collectibility is defined in terms of whether or not there are live references to an object. Local variables and method arguments go out of scope at the end of the method (or the block they're declared in), regardless of whether or not they're declared `final`. Going out of scope means the reference is "dead". The object itself may still have live references from elsewhere.

In this particular case, the formal method parameters are declared `final` so that they can be used in an inner class. As mentioned above, the inner class would copy these references for its own use. Thus, in this particular case, the `Authenticator` object would have references to the `String` objects referred to by `a` and `b`.

Simplistically speaking, the more references to an object there are, the harder it would be to qualify as garbage illegible for collection. The underlying factor, however, is the *liveness* of these references, not whether or not they're `final`.

---

#### On profiling

It's good to understand the concepts to clear any doubts on memory usage/performance issues; it's better to just profile and see if the issues are real, and fix them as necessary. A well-designed system should be highly adaptable to these kinds of changes.

Comment: I think the OP knows the purpose of final, they were just nervous about introducing it in the parameter list of an overridden method.

Comment: Nice answer. Could you link to the 'nasty reflection attacks' that can make Strings mutable? I'm morbidly curious (and always worried about security).

Comment: @Alex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481862/how-to-limit-setaccessible-to-only-legitimate-uses  -- essentially using `setAccessible` you can access private variables etc.

Answer (score 3):

No, the `final` on an argument only influences the local copy of the argument on the stack frame of the method. It does not in any way influence or change the value passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `final` doesn't change the signature or create any other issues.  Thus, it is fine to use in a method specified by an interface (for instance).  It only makes a difference to code inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

Making the variables `final` does not have anything to do with security or memory allocation. It does not have any impact on security or memory use.