# SmartGWT ListGrid final

Tags: java, static, smartgwt, final, listgrid

I realized that ListGrid must be always Final. For me a static object would be the best because I would like to modify its properties from another class.

In my project to have a clear code I created several classes.

1. class `DataGrid extends ListGrid` which set up the properties of the new object and also fills up with data. An @Override method adds button to my grid object.
2. class `PopupWindow extend Window` which is used to create a Window object when you click on the edit button in the ListGrid. In the Window there are some textboxes where you can add new data and a Submit button. OnClick event of the Submit button will write the data to a MySQL server, and **should update the grid with the actual data** (query from the MySQL). This is the part I can not implement.
3. In the Entry Point class onModuleLoad I just have this grid code:

   final DataGrid grid_far = new DataGrid();
   grid_far.setGridData();

I am new in java, maybe I should not use so many classes, just put everything in the Entry Point class onModuleLoad()?

If in the PopupWindow extends Window class I declare Button OnClick to run onModuleLoad() methode from Entry Point class, will this duplicate my web page?
I mean doing this:

```
 EntryPointClass ep = new EntryPointClass();
 ep.onModuleLoad();
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking: I suspect it is about scoping in the inner loop (where you can only use `final` variables). Perhaps you need to refine your question?

Comment: Thanks. From your answer it is now clear for me that I can not use outer variables in an inner loop. If there was any way to make ListGrid object `static` then I would not think about overhanding the ListGrid object. So, my main interest is about a `static` ListGrid.

Comment: I now removed `implements EntryPoint` from the main class, and so managed to make public `static` void onModuleLoad(). This let me use MainClass.onModuleLoad() from another class, and when I run this method, grid will be re-generated (at least I hope not duplicated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- "ListGrid must be always Final"

This is not necessary. Its possible to create ListGrid variables as non-final.
You must have seen samples where ListGrid variables were declared as final, but its for some other reason.

For example, its not possible to use a non-final local variable (one declared inside a method) in an anonymous inner class.
So, in order to access local variables from an inner class, they need to be declared final.
In SmartGWT/Swing/etc. inner classes are used to implement various callback functionalities like event handling.

```
public class Screen {

    ListGrid grid1 = new ListGrid();
    TextItem text1 = new TextItem("text1", "Text 1");

    public void initialize() {
        // normally its not required to create subclasses of ListGrid/Button/Window/etc.
        // unless a significant change in their behavior is needed

        ListGrid grid2 = new ListGrid();
        // setup grid properties
        // set grid fields

        TextItem text2 = new TextItem("text2", "Text 2");

        final ListGrid grid3 = new ListGrid();
        final TextItem text3 = new TextItem("text3", "Text 3");

        IButton button = new IButton("Edit");
        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() { // this is declaring an anonymous inner class
            public void onClick(ClickEvent clickEvent) { // this method is a member of that anonymous inner class
                // out of three ListGrid and thee TextItem instances, only following can be accessed in this method/class
                //   grid1, text1 (these are not local variables, inner class can access outer class members without any issue)
                //   grid3, text3 (as they are final, even though local variables)
            }
        });

        // that does not mean, grid2 and text2 can not be used, they can be, just not inside an anonymous inner class
        // e.g.-
        DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
        form.setFields(text2);

        VLayout layout = new VLayout();
        layout.addMember(grid2);
    }
}
```

Check following links for more details on using local variables in inner classes
[Inner class and local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338708/java-inner-class-and-local-variables)
[Question about local final variable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947352/question-about-local-final-variable-in-java)

- "static object would be the best because I would like to modify its properties from another class"

There are better ways to communicate among objects than using static variables.

- "maybe I should not use so many classes, just put everything in the Entry Point class onModuleLoad()"

Its better to keep code in onModuleLoad() to a minimum.
Number of classes needed depend on what you try to implement.

- "EntryPoint"

You can not remove EntryPoint implementation as that is where GWT will handover execution to create the application.
And onModuleLoad() is called by GWT/JavaScript engine for that.
It must not be called by your code.

Go through the [SmartGWT showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/) including code samples.
Refer [SmartGWT API](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/) for more details.
There are multiple ways to create the UI to achieve the same results.

Communication with server to send/receive data in SmartGWT is a topic on its own.

Possible implemention guideline.

```
public class EntryPointClass implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        ApplicationScreen screen = new ApplicationScreen();

        HStack drawArea = new HStack();
        drawArea.setWidth100();
        drawArea.setHeight100();
        drawArea.addMember(screen.getComponents());
        drawArea.draw();
    }
}

public class ApplicationScreen { // this class does not need to extend from a widget
    public Canvas getComponents() {
        // a method that prepares the interface
        // using a from+grid type layout, without a popup window

        ListGrid grid = getListGrid();

        DynamicForm form = getDynamicForm(grid); // have to pass grid in order to add/update records on button events

        VLayout layout = new VLayout();
        layout.addMember(form);
        layout.addMember(grid);

        return layout;
    }

    private DynamicForm getDynamicForm(final ListGrid grid) { // have to declare grid as final to access from event handler inner classes
        final TextItem text1 = new TextItem("text1", "Text 1");  // have to declare as final for same reason

        ButtonItem saveButton = new ButtonItem("Save");
        saveButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
                // use text1, grid and other components to save form values and refresh grid
            }
        });

        // creating and configuring form
        DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();
        form.setWidth100();
        form.setFields(text1, saveButton);

        return form;
    }

    private ListGrid getListGrid() {
        // preparing grid fields
        ListGridField field1 = new ListGridField("field1", "Field 1");

        // creating and configuring grid
        ListGrid grid = new ListGrid(); // not final, does not need to be
        grid.setWidth100();
        grid.setFields(field1);

        return grid;
    }
}
```