# SmartGWT: How to create a tab in a pane dynamically by clicking a tree node in another pane

Tags: smartgwt

I'm new to smartGWT. I saw a tutorial in the following link 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/advanced-smartgwt-tutorial-part-2.html

Here there are two classes one is main area and another is navigation area. Navigation area contains tree nodes . When i click tree node it displays a popup , but i want to create a tab with click event of a node.

I tried in the following way but it didn't work . I think it added the tabs since the mainarea is already got loaded it is not taking any effect

Main Area Class has this code:

```
public class MainArea extends SectionStack {

final TabSet topTabSet = new TabSet();

public static MainArea mainareaobj;
public static MainArea getInstance()
{
    if(mainareaobj==null)
    {
        mainareaobj=new MainArea();
    }
    return mainareaobj;
}
public MainArea() {

    super();
    this.setOverflow(Overflow.AUTO);

    topTabSet.setTabBarPosition(Side.TOP);  
    topTabSet.setTabBarAlign(Side.LEFT);
    SectionStackSection section2 = new SectionStackSection("TabSection2");  
    section2.setExpanded(true);  
   section2.addItem(topTabSet);


    this.addSection(section2);
}
```

Following code is of navigation grid

```
public class NavigationTreeGrid extends TreeGrid {
public String scenario_Name;
public Tab scenarioTab;
MainArea obj=MainArea.getInstance();
public NavigationTreeGrid() {
    setShowOpenIcons(false);
    setShowDropIcons(false);
    setShowSelectedStyle(true);  
    setShowPartialSelection(true);  
    setCascadeSelection(false);
    setCanSort(false);
    setShowConnectors(true);
    setShowHeader(false);
    setLoadDataOnDemand(false);
    setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.SINGLE);

    Tree data = new Tree();
    data.setModelType(TreeModelType.CHILDREN);

    data.setRoot(
            new TreeNode("root", 
                    new TreeNode("rootNode",
                            new TreeNode("Node1"), new TreeNode("Node2"),new TreeNode("Node3"),new TreeNode("Node4"),new TreeNode("Node5"))) 

    );

    setData(data);

    addNodeClickHandler(new NodeClickHandler() {            
        @Override
        public void onNodeClick(NodeClickEvent event) {
            scenario_Name = event.getNode().getName();

            obj.topTabSet.addTab(createTab(scenario_Name));

        }
    });

}

public Tab createTab(String tabName)
{
    scenarioTab=new Tab(tabName);
    scenarioTab.setCanClose(true);
    //scenarioTab.setWidth(300);
    return scenarioTab;
}
```

can any plz help me

Comment: Check this [sample in SmartGWT showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_tabs_add_remove).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `scenarioTab.setPane(canvas)` and add some content to the new tab.  Could be other problems but you didn't post enough code.

Comment: If you still want to see entire code plz check the above url in  description , page contains all classes

Comment: if you see the description it is not about setting contents of the tab. it is about creating the tabs. So the answer is when ever i click the node tab is created but not displayed on UI. So i have to redraw the pane where i'm adding the tabset

Answer (score 1):

Properly add navigation tree and section stack to the primary display component in `EntryPoint.onModuleLoad()`.

**Even though `MainArea` instance gets initialized inside `NavigationTreeGrid`, it must be separately added to the layout.**

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
        HStack drawArea = new HStack();
        drawArea.setWidth100();
        drawArea.setHeight100();

        drawArea.addMember(new NavigationTreeGrid());
        drawArea.addMember(MainArea.getInstance());

        drawArea.draw();
}
```

That will create the grid and node click events will add new, but empty, tabs to the tab set.
Will need to use `scenarioTab.setPane(<tab content>)` in `NavigationTreeGrid.createTab()` to populate the tabs.

Your code works as I mentioned above, but can be improved.
Check "[SmartGWT ListGrid final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313936/smartgwt-listgrid-final/16326492#16326492)" for another way to create a simple screen.

Comment: Thank you. i got it . when ever i'm clicking the node i'm redrawing the tabset. So it will redraw the tabset.

Comment: Hi actually i added the navigation and main area correctly . but after clicking node i'm not redrawing it . that is why it is not showing the created tabs .

Comment: @bhasker When I tried your code, as you have posted here, I was able to see tabs getting created on node clicks without explicit drawing of MainArea/Tree/Tabs/TabSet/etc. I assume this code is used with other components. When you say you were not redrawing after a node click, was it one of MainArea/Tree/Tabs/TabSet or main component (drawArea) or something else?

Comment: Hi if you see my previous code there is no redrawing of tabset . that is why it not showing in the main area. But now it will show the tabset with redraw. that is what i meant in above comment. sorry if i confused you.

Answer (score -1):

```
addNodeClickHandler(new NodeClickHandler() {            
        @Override
        public void onNodeClick(NodeClickEvent event) {
            scenario_Name = event.getNode().getName();
            obj.topTabSet.addTab(createTab(scenario_Name));
           obj.topTabSet.redraw();
        }
    });

}
```

just   obj.topTabSet.redraw(); will solve the problem. so here whenever we click the node it will create the tab and redraw the tabset.