# Where does the Java store the final member and static member?

Tags: java, memory-management, static, final

I know that the static method and non-static method of a class all store in the method area.

But I am really in doubt that where does Java stores the final variable(constant) members and static variable members of an object.

For example,

```
class A{
     private final int a = 1;
     private static int b = 2;
     private static final int c = 3;
     //other codes...
}
```

I wonder where does Java store a,b,c in the memory. Heap,Stack,or Method area?

======update=====
Hey,Thanks for your help.And please allow me to share a link about the components of jvm:http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm2.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387989/where-is-a-static-method-and-a-static-variable-stored-in-java-in-heap-or-in-sta

Comment: @almasshaikh Yes.But most the material I have google, only tell me that the where to store local final variable.For example ,this one[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947352/question-about-local-final-variable-in-java].

Comment: @vikeng21 Thanks for your comments, and maybe click this link for reference:http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm2.html

Comment: @RRR Thanks for your comment.But I also wonder about the storage of the final members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a Java virtual machine instance, information about loaded types is stored in a logical area of memory called the `method area`.Memory for class (static) variables declared in the class is taken from the method area.

All instance variables will be stored in `heap area`, including final members.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.And what about the storage of the final members?

Comment: Even it is final variable still it is an instance variable. So, it will be stored in heap area along with object data.

Answer (score 0):

On my test, I have this conclusion.

```
   1. private final int a = 1; // heap with object
   2. private static int b = 2; // class variables of Method Area
   3. private static final int c = 3; // run-time constant pool of Method Area
```

1. final int is created on the constructor. it means it relates to object.
2. static int is created on static {}. it means it relates to static variable
   static variable equals class variables of Method Area.
3. static final int is in constant pool and there is no related code. it means
   it will be referred to at runtime.

[Bytecode Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvt30.jpg)