# Injection Methods/Variables: public or Not?

Tags: java, security, spring, jpa

Many Java frameworks allow class members used for injection to be declared non-public. For example, injected variables in Spring and EJB 3 may be private. JPA allows properties of a persistent class to be protected or package-private.

We know it's better to declare methods non-public if you can. That being said, if I'm not mistaken, allowing these frameworks to access non-public members only works with the default Java security manager. Doesn't it mean that custom code can also gain access to non-public member via reflection by calling setAccessible(), **which would compromise security**?

Which begs this question: What is the best practice when setting the access level for injection methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to limit setAccessible to only "legitimate" uses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481862/how-to-limit-setaccessible-to-only-legitimate-uses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically a class needs to opt-in to a persistence mechanism. For instance, Java serialisatoin requires a class to implement `java.io.Serializable`. It is the responsibility of classes that implement `Serializable` to ensure that they are secure.  Where a library allows poking of privates through an external configuration file, then that should not be trusted - reflection is really dangerous and its use is usually messed up.

Of course if you do find a vulnerability, please report it to the appropriate group.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running untrusted code in the same JVM as your application, and you're using the default security manager settings, then yeah, that could be a security hole. This is something you need to be aware of, but in practice, this situation is pretty rare.