# Is it possible to use Java Reflection to print out attributes of the parent class?

Tags: java, reflection, attributes, parent

is it possible to use Java Reflection to print out the attributes of a parent class.

Comment: You can navigate the class hierarchy, you can reflect class attributes, so why not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you could do something like this:

```
Class<?> parentClass = getClass().getSuperclass();

Field[] fields = parentClass.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    System.out.println("field: " + field.getName());
}

Method[] methods = parentClass.getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method method : methods) {
    System.out.println("method: " + method.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given an appropriately permissive security policy, it is possible to print out *any* class/instance's attributes using reflection. See [How to limit setAccessible to only "legitimate" uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481862/how-to-limit-setaccessible-to-only-legitimate-uses) for some interesting discussion.