# Is it possible to use Java Reflection or various techniques to check if a class has a parent class?

Tags: java, reflection, parent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use Java Reflection to print out attributes of the parent class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099128/is-it-possible-to-use-java-reflection-to-print-out-attributes-of-the-parent-class)

Hi, is it possible to use Java Reflection or various techniques to check if a class has a parent class?

This thought came as something for a need to create a utility class that takes in an object, print out its attributes, and if a parent class exists, to print out the attributes of the parent class.

**Edit** I meant to ask if there was a way to keep checking if a class had a mother class all the way up to the Object class.

Comment: What's the difference between this question and [the one you asked ~20 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099128)?

Comment: ... every class has a parent class - except for `java.lang.Object` ...

Comment: Sorry i edited the question slightly. The idea is to ask if there was a technique to keep traversing "upwards" eventually to the Object and printing attributes belonging to each class along the way.

Comment: @Chin, there is indeed a technique for this, it is called a _loop_ ;-) Honestly, the accepted answer to your previous question shows you how to get the direct superclass of a class, and that's all you need to solve this problem.

Comment: @Peter - a *loop*? Looks more like a job for Mr. Recursion ;)

Comment: @Andreas_D, either of them can do the job, but I thought the Loop sisters are more widely known than their somewhat mysterious cousin :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
Class<?> superClass = MyClass.class.getSuperClass();
```

All superclasses:

```
public static void printSuperClass(Class<?> clazz) {
  if (clazz == null) return;

  Class<?> superclass = clazz.getSuperClass();
  System.out.println(clazz.getName() + " extends " + superclass.getName());
  printSuperClass(superclass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to walk up the parent classes.

```
for(Class clazz=object.getClass(); clazz!=null; clazz=clazz.getSuperClass())
    System.out.println(clazz);
```

Note: Object, primitives, interfaces and array's all have `null` as a superclass.