# How to find the number of methods in the class

Tags: java, reflection

I want to create a Program that takes another Java program as input and should return number of methods in the class and also number of attributes.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use reflection:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

edit: Question already asked here: [Is it possible to use Java Reflection to print out attributes of the parent class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099128/is-it-possible-to-use-java-reflection-to-print-out-attributes-of-the-parent-clas)

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Test.class.getMethods().length);
        System.out.println(Test.class.getFields().length);
    }

}
```

Comment: Best not to answer `homework` questions with the actual code, but rather (as Walkerneo did) with a pointer to how to proceed to build one's own solution.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are asking us a homework question. Look at the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/), in package `java.lang.reflect` and the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) class. Then when you have some code you want us to help with, post again.