# Are private members really more "secure" in Java?

Tags: java, oop

Learning Java I was sometimes taught to use the `private` access modifier so as not to expose "sensitive information" to other classes, as if this could open a legitimate security hole. But I've never encountered a situation in which restricting member visibility was more than a convenience for modelling a program in an object-oriented fashion.

**Are `private` fields and functions in Java classes actually more "secure" than otherwise?**

---

**EDIT** -- Compilation of best answers.

Why `private` does not mean "secure":

- *decompilers* allow static look at bytecode
- *reflection* library allows runtime access to private members

What `private` is good for:

- *maintainability* of code due to forcing method-level access
- *modularity* of code by hiding implementation details

Comment: I agree with the answers. Your teachers didn't understand the point of access modifiers. It has nothing to do with security.

Comment: Just one point: it is possible to prevent dangerous code, like reflection used to change access level, calls to Unsafe etc, by configuring a policy for Java's security manager. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Policy.html

Comment: Actually, hard private state is important (especially on platforms with very different concerns, like embedded systems with limited resources which cannot afford process separation, or blockchains) and access modifiers (or closures which can do more or less the same) are a natural mechanism for it, so it's a shame they're removing SecurityManager. See e.g. https://agoric.com/blog/all/taxonomy-of-security-issues/.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never heard of it -- in any serious sense -- as a security issue.  I mean, decompilers work. You can use them to figure out what's going on inside the bytecode.

Having `private` members is a maintainability issue.  If I only give you method-level access to my internals, then my only responsibility is to ensure that my API methods continue to work. I'm not locked into using a `Double` versus a `BigDecimal` on the insides, so long as my methods continue to return `Double`s (for instance).

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not more "secure" in that sense, though some (very poor) books on Java try to explain `private` in that way. If an attacker had the ability to cause arbitrary Java code to be run in your process, all "security" is already gone. And as another answer already mentioned, reflection can bypass the `private` access modifier.

Answer (score 1):

`private` isn't really for security, since reflection can bypass it (modulo classloader/secure classloader stuff). It serves as an indication of intent, and as barrier to one type of programming error.

But consider a third-party API--API users don't even *see* the `private` properties or methods. It's not just about your *own* code, it's about what code is exposed to others. (Again looking at it from a "I'm not trying to break in to the code" standpoint.)

Answer (score 1):

As far as security goes, the answer is "not really": determined hackers could get to your private fields and call your private functions with a little bit of reflection; all they need is a JAR with your code in it.

Although hiding "sensitive" information does not make your class more *secure*, it makes it (along with systems built from it) a lot more *maintainable*. So this answer is not an excuse for making all members of your classes public.

Answer (score 1):

I agree in general with the answers so far (i.e. that `private` is really for code hygiene not real security). Various answers have pointed out that you can bypass `private` using reflection. Note that you can, in turn, disable reflection if you enable a Java SecurityManager. See particularly the [ReflectPermission](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appA.html#ReflectPermission).  However, security managers are rarely used (outside the normal browser sandboxing).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the principles of making everything private where possible only apply if you adhere to the [open-closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) otherwise if people get used to the idea of editing the internals of existing classes instead of extending them they may well change the encapsulation of private member variables be it through making them accessible through mutators and accessors or changing the access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I think the meaning of "security" by your instructor was not about keeping hackers out, but rather keeping bugs out.  By making everything as private as possible, you limit the ways that one class can mess with another class without it knowing.  This is an example of [Modular Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming).

Answer (score 0):

Btw: reflection in Java actually allows you to override access modifiers of fields of objects. See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) and  an [example](http://www.javareference.com/jrexamples/viewexample.jsp?id=113).