# How can I tell when my code has been reflected?

Tags: java, reflection

I am a newer in Java, I know anyone can use reflection to get private methods and private data, but how can I konw whether my code being reflected? Or, I don't want to my code be reflected, is there any methods to prevent it?

I don't know how to do

Comment: Since Java 9, things in a module cannot be reflected on by default in another module, unless you open them.

Comment: You could in theory inspect the current stack trace to see if you're being called by "normal" code or via reflection, but that would be quite costly. What problem are you trying to solve, because this is a very unusual requirement and might by a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). If you told us the underlying requirement, we might be able to suggest better/simpler solutions.

Comment: The term “anyone” is misleading. The code of another Java class running in the same environment can do that. If you have a problem with that, you should first ask yourself, how the class got into your environment.

Comment: @Holger The code is not necessarily being run on their environment. I'm just guessing here, but the question sounds like they want to do some kind of copy/abuse protection.

Comment: Is the code you are trying to protect some kind of library that users integrate into their applications? Is it a standalone application? Is it running in a web/application server?

Comment: @Torben it doesn’t change the fact that someone who can insert a class into the environment could also change the code of the class in question. Changing `private` to `public` means changing two bits. Or just access the data *before* the class trying to make them private gets them.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201603/are-private-members-really-more-secure-in-java

Comment: @JoachimSauer there is no guaranty that the use of Reflection is visible in the stack trace. In fact, a caller being able to use Reflection with access override can also access the method without Reflection, e.g. by generating a non-reflective accessor class.

Comment: @Holger I was not arguing about that. My comment was about the assumption and the possible reason for the "XY problem" mentioned by Joachim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking the question is indicative of a misunderstanding of how java works.

If you run code you do not trust *on your VM*, **you lose**. JVMs are not designed to allow sandboxing segments of code or threads. Untrusted code can do *a lot more* than reflect into your private methods. It can waste all memory, deadlock threads, JVMTI-connect to its own JVM and change absolutely anything it wants (including adding and remove code), and so on. In other words, if someone with malicious intent manages to get your VM to run something they made, it's over. Your JVM is now fully compromised.

The solution is, obviously, *not* to run code you don't trust, a simple catch all solution.

If you need to run java code you don't trust, you fire up an entirely separate JVM and place *that* in a sandbox (which you set up using your OS, not by trying to configure a JVM).

Java is not designed to do this particularly well. For example, java just doesn't let you configure it with very little memory, and it is not very good at safely sharing common resources (such as the code of String, something that most JVM programs will use). If you have a need to run loads of code you don't trust, you may want to look into platforms that are really good at that, such as WebAssembly (which isn't *just* a thing you can run in browser, you can run WA code in a JVM too, and that *is* fully sandboxable. However, compiling java code to WebAsm isn't a good idea).

Yes, there is the SecurityManager which is theoretically designed to sandbox. However:

- It is deprecated, for removal. Pretty soon (if not already with JDK21), java won't support it at all.
- It only blocks specific calls, it does not protect against e.g. flooding memory or deadlocking.
- "Nobody" (rounding down here) was using it, and the OpenJDK team wasn't actively pushing it either. As a consequence, I rate the odds that there is just **no** way for malicious code to find a gap in the SecurityManager to be incredibly low. Think about it: If you manage to find a way to run machine code on a host machine simply with some javascript a browser runs, you can sell that for tens of millions if not more to hacker rings. If you find a hole in the SM? Well, what are you going to do with that? Maybe someone will give you 10k for it, tops. Far fewer people are looking for those holes.

As a consequence, the basic answer to your question is: **You can't, and that does not actually matter**. Or, rather:

Even if you could, that doesn't accomplish anything. Hence, whatever you thought you were stopping or protecting against with a hypothetical 'please, no reflection' change, you actually won't.

Note that using the module system to stop reflective access also doesn't work, in that there are still plenty of ways around it if you intentionally want to get around it, and `--add-opens` will always work to get around it, that is the point of `--add-opens`.

Comment: The `--add-opens` option is not required, so you could, in theory, use a JVM not supporting this option. But you still have to ensure that your code running in that JVM has not been manipulated before the JVM is started. Regarding the security manager, it’s worth adding that it entirely works under the assumption that all code you’re using (of all libraries) is written by security aware people, understanding that if they’re trusted to perform a particular option, they have to ensure that untrusted code can’t make them do unintended things through carefully crafted input. See log4j for reality…

Comment: To be honest, most libraries are not written so they can be *safely* used with a SecurityManager. Yes, some have the `AccessController.doPrivileged` calls so they still work when a SecurityManager is installed, and still open a big hole when granting them the permissions they need. [I wrote a lengthy reddit post about that](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/s5i5td/youre_running_untrusted_code/ht2qzdy/).

Comment: @JohannesKuhn that’s precisely what I meant. The concept of the security manager is built on a wrong assumption about the libraries. The log4j disaster demonstrated that you can’t assume that awareness. Even worse, the design mistake of treating class initializers like ordinary caller dependent methods even taught the authors to mindlessly put `doPrivileged` around everything…

Comment: @JohannesKuhn by the way, `@CallerSensitive` does not work like `doPrivileged`. It allows specific actions regarding the caller sensitive method, e.g. `Method.invoke` allows the caller to invoke a `private` method in its own class, but beyond this, it works like an ordinary invocation, i.e. when said `private` method performs I/O operations, the caller’s callers are still considered.

Comment: If you use `Method.invoke` to invoke an other `@CallerSensitive` method, it works like that method was called directly. And that includes `AccessController.doPrivileged`. No library (just a guess) is stupid enough to let you supply your own `PrivilegedAction` that is then passed to `AccessController.doPrivileged`. Except a lot of libraries allow exactly that with some indirection through `Method.invoke`.

Comment: My point about `@CallerSensitive` is: You have to carefully inspect the arguments and where the result goes with them. Leaking the result of `MethodHandles.lookup()`?  Bad. Leaking the result of `Class.getDeclared*`? Possibly allow an attacker to bypass the `RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers"`. Calling `Method.invoke` with on a user supplied method and arguments? All of the above.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your patience. I have created a plug-in for the platform in Java and as others will be doing secondary development, I don't want them to modify the member variables in my Java classes while the platform is running, or to see the contents of my Jar packages.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn but that applies to anything. Creating an `InputStream` is not caller-sensitive, but obviously, passing it to untrusted code afterwards can cause problems. `Class.forName("Foo")` is a caller-sensitive method, but `Foo.class` is not (even a method), but both do exactly the same and passing the result to someone else has the same implications.

Comment: @Holger Indeed. We can spend 5000 pages on the details of trying to run untrusted code on JVMs, but, the executive summary of those pages would be a single word: "__don't__", and by and large that would be an accurate and sufficient summary of it all.

Comment: @AYuan you have three options. [A] forget about it. Plug-in authors can mess with all the things. You accept this. Or use out-of-band systems to ensure they don't (that's what e.g. apple's app store review process is). [B] Write an allow-list model that scans a class file and always rejects them unless that class file only does safe things. Nobody does it this way and you'll be tempted to work on a denylist model. Don't. Denylists don't work and you won't know it until you get hacked. [C] Run the plug-in in a separate JVM (and sandbox that one, using e.g. chroot stuff on posixen).

Comment: @AYuan yes, option B and C are __incredibly__ complicated, and C is extremely resource intensive. I know you don't want to hear it, but you have to get used to this: __You cannot do what you want here__.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Thank you for your reply, I have learnt a lot!!!

Answer (score -1):

In Java, reflection allows access to private methods and data, although it should be used judiciously. While you cannot completely prevent reflection on your code, there are measures you can take to make it more challenging or discourage unwanted reflection.

- **Access Modifiers**: Use appropriate access modifiers (public, protected, or private) for methods and data. Utilize the most restrictive access modifier (private whenever possible) to limit access to the necessary parts of your code.

```
    public class MyClass {
        private int privateData;
    
        private void privateMethod() {
            System.out.println("Private method");
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MyClass obj = new MyClass();
            obj.privateData = 10; // Accessing private data within the class
            obj.privateMethod(); // Invoking private method within the class
        }
    }
```

- **Immutable Classes**: Design your classes to be immutable. Immutable classes have final fields and lack setter methods, reducing the need for reflection.

```
    public final class ImmutableClass {
        private final int immutableData;
    
        public ImmutableClass(int data) {
            this.immutableData = data;
        }
    
        public int getImmutableData() {
            return immutableData;
        }
    }
```

- **Security Managers**: Java's Security Managers can restrict certain features, including reflection. By configuring a security policy and enabling a Security Manager, you gain control over the permissions granted to your Java application.

```
    grant {
        permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
    };
```

- **Obfuscation**: Employ obfuscation techniques to make your code harder to understand and reverse-engineer. Obfuscation tools can rename variables, obfuscate control flow, and perform other transformations to diminish code readability.

It's important to note that these measures provide challenges but are not foolproof. Determined attackers may find ways to bypass them. Focus on writing secure, well-designed code rather than solely relying on prevention techniques.

Remember that reflection can be a legitimate and useful tool in specific scenarios, such as testing or dependency injection frameworks. It offers powerful capabilities, but its usage should be responsible and well-understood.

Comment: The security manager has been marked [“Deprecated, for removal”](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/SecurityManager.html). It was only useful for trying to control the activities of external code you let into your own runtime, e.g. applets. If you distrust the code, the better option is not to let the code into your environment in the first place. On the other hand, if you don’t control the environment, you can’t trust the security manager of that environment anyway.

Comment: Looks like ChatGPT output.