# How to avoid using reflections to create a new instance

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, singleton

I have a `Singleton` class which is implemented with on-demand-holder initialization. According to [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3) article, It is still vulnerable to the reflection attacks.

**How can I prevent this from java reflections to invoke private constructor and create new instances?**

This is my `SingletonTest` class:

```
class SingletonTest{
    public SingletonTest(){
        System.out.println("before SingletonTest()");
        Singleton s1 = Singleton.getSingleton();
        Singleton s2 = Singleton.getSingleton();

        System.out.printf("s1 Hash: %d\n",System.identityHashCode(s1));
        System.out.printf("s2 Hash: %d\n",System.identityHashCode(s2));

        Constructor<?> con = Singleton.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[1];
        con.setAccessible(true);

        //System.out.println(con.toString());

        try {
            Singleton s3 = (Singleton) con.newInstance();
            System.out.printf("s3 Hash: %d\n",System.identityHashCode(s3));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("after SingletonTest()");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new SingletonTest();
    }
}
```

This is my `Singleton` class:

```
final public class Singleton {
    private Singleton(){
        System.out.println("Singleton created...!");
    }

    public static Singleton getSingleton(){
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    static class SingletonHolder{
            private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    public void doStuff(){
        System.out.println("dostuff....");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
before SingletonTest()
Singleton created...!
s1 Hash: 1924489565
s2 Hash: 1924489565
Singleton created...!
s3 Hash: 294316734
after SingletonTest()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about check and throw exception in constructor?

```
private Singleton(){
    if(SingletonHolder.INSTANCE !=null)
       throw new IllegalStateException("Not allowed!");
}
```

another possibility is, implement your singleton pattern with java Enum.

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
    public void doStuff(){...}

}
```

Comment: thanks It is working :); I tried `java.lang.InstantiationException` which isn't a RunTimeException. I read somewhere you can control it using SecurityManager. Any idea on it?

Comment: @tiriboy how about throw `InstantiationError`? Or you want it to be `RuntimeEx`, just `new RuntimeException()`? or I didn't get you?

Comment: yeah, it seems more self-describable. tnx.

Comment: You can still [set `INSTANCE` to `null` using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection) before calling the constructor.

Comment: @FlorentBayle: But it declared as `final` O.o any solution?

Comment: @tiriboy It may not be possible, but you can have a look at `SecurityManager`, and at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481862/how-to-limit-setaccessible-to-only-legitimate-uses.

Comment: My idea is to reference an instance of SecurityManager. However I don't have much experience about that part, so I cannot give much hints. You can give the enum approach a try.