# PowerMockito: How to mock final static variable initialization

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, powermock

I'm writing test cases for Legacy code. I have a scenario like this.

```
class A
{
  static final X = getUI().getResourceX();

  A(){}

  ....some methods to test....

}
```

I have to create spy object from class `A`. But while creating object it calls `getUI` method which returns `null` and it caused a NullpointerException. So, how I eliminate getting null from getUI method?

Comment: Well, what does getUI() do? You'll have to create a situation in which it won't return `null`.

Comment: @ray getUI method returns customized table model

Answer (score 0):

First I would advise to have a look here:
[How to mock a static final variable using JUnit, EasyMock or PowerMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697531/how-to-mock-a-static-final-variable-using-junit-easymock-or-powermock)

In general, to fix your issue you can go with this:

```
     Mockito.when(getUI().getResourceX()).thenReturn(whatYouNeed);
```