# Mocking complex Java object

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermockito

Is there any way of mocking a really complex object, statically initialized in a class, without modifying source code?

The code looks something like this.

```
public class SomeType {

  private static final ComplexType TYPE = new ComplexType();

  public SomeType() {}

  public Object process(int id, String content) { 
    ...
    TYPE.something();
    ...
  }
}
```

Attempting to test the behavior of the `SomeType` class by calling

```
new SomeType().process(1, "<some text>");
```

requires mocking somehow the `ComplexType` object, which has numerous other complex objects statically initialized in its definition, plus network-intensive operations during initialization. As a result, `mock()` or `spy()` do not work, since the `ComplexType` object gets initialized on referencing the `SomeType` class. It appears that, to mock the `ComplexType` object all its complex dependencies need to be prepared, which makes the test code complicated.

Another approach suggested is modifying the `static final` field `TYPE` via reflection. However that won't work either, since it takes place after the initialization of `TYPE`, so the error caused by the initialization has already taken place.

Comment: Is this useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697531/how-to-mock-a-static-final-variable-using-junit-easymock-or-powermock

Comment: Not sure I understood your problem, but maybe `MockBean` is what you are looking for. Have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html