# Java Reflection - IllegalAccessException on "set" if preceded by "get" operation

Tags: java, reflection

I was trying to change the value of a `private static final` field using reflection (yes, that's probably a very bad idea to begin with, I know).
And, well, for the most part it works fine using following code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        System.out.println("Before :: " + B.get());
        Field field = B.class.getDeclaredField("arr");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        // System.out.println("Peek   :: " + ((String[]) field.get(null))[0]);
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(null, new String[] { "Good bye, World!" });
        System.out.println("After  :: " + B.get());
    }
}

class B {
    private static final String[] arr = new String[] { "Hello, World!" };

    public static String get() {
        return arr[0];
    }
}
```

Which prints as expected:

```
Before :: Hello, World!
After  :: Good bye, World!
```

Problems arise when I try to `get` the field value via reflection prior to `set`ting it.
That is, if I uncomment the commented line in above sample, I get the following:

```
Before :: Hello, World!
Peek   :: Hello, World!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not set static final [Ljava.lang.String; field B.arr to [Ljava.lang.String;
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwFinalFieldIllegalAccessException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwFinalFieldIllegalAccessException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:80)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedStaticObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeQualifiedStaticObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
        at A.main(A.java:14)
```

Why is this happening??
I tried to set again the `accessible` flag after the call to `get` but it doesn't help.
I tried many other things that don't seem to help either...

Thanks for your help!

---

**Edit**: there is an element of answer in [Using reflection to change static final File.separatorChar for unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474017/using-reflection-to-change-static-final-file-separatorchar-for-unit-testing/2474242#2474242) (see "**Important update**" by @Rogério).

> **Important update**: the above solution *does not* work in all cases. If the field is made accessible and read through Reflection before it gets reset, an `IllegalAccessException` is thrown. It fails because the Reflection API creates internal `FieldAccessor` objects which are cached and reused (see the java.lang.reflect.Field#acquireFieldAccessor(boolean) implementation).
>   Example test code which fails:
>
> ```
> Field f = File.class.getField("separatorChar"); f.setAccessible(true); f.get(null);
> // call setFinalStatic as before: throws IllegalAccessException
> ```

Sadly, it doesn't say anything about how to work around it... How do I "reset" the field?

Comment: It's final, cannot be set

Comment: Interestingly, if you get the value the normal way (not via reflection) you don't get the error when you later set it via reflection.

Comment: An interesting question. Just digging through the code to see where this comes from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## A very bad idea, indeed.

I'm not sure how deeply one should go into details when answering this question. But here's a short summary of what happens:

When you do the reflective `Field#get` call, the the call will internally (after a few security checks) be delegated to a `sun.reflect.FieldAccessor`. This is an internal interface that, as the name suggests, provides access to field values. The `FieldAccessor` instance that is used internally is created lazily, "cached" for later use, and even shared among multiple `Field` instances.

There are many different implementations of the `FieldAccessor` interface. These implementations are specialized for the various cases of normal Fields, static Fields, or private Fields that have been made accessible by calling `setAccessible(true)`. For example, in your case, there is a `UnsafeQualifiedStaticObjectFieldAccessorImpl` involved, and the name already suggests that this is only one of a few dozen specializations.

Many of these `FieldAccessor` implementations store an internal *state*, which describe some properties of the field. For example, whether the field is "read only" or **`final`** (!).

The point is: The `FieldAccessor` that is created when you do the reflective `Field#get` call is the same that will later be used for the reflective `Field#set` call. **But** when the `FieldAccessor` is created, the field is still considered to be **`final`**. You are changing this only **after** you created the `FieldAccessor`.

So the easiest solution is to make sure that the `final`-status of the field is changed **before** you do this first reflective call. This way, the `FieldAccessor` that is created internally is one that operates on a "non-final" field:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before :: " + B.get());
        Field field = B.class.getDeclaredField("arr");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        System.out.println("Peek   :: " + ((String[]) field.get(null))[0]);
        field.set(null, new String[] { "Good bye, World!" });
        System.out.println("After  :: " + B.get());
    }
}

class B {
    private static final String[] arr = new String[] { "Hello, World!" };

    public static String get() {
        return arr[0];
    }
}
```

---

I should not mention this. People will **do** this. But however:

Technically, it is also possible to `brutallyHackYourWayThroughInternalClasses` and modify the `FieldAccessor` that was created internally, so that it afterwards allows modifying the field, even though it initially was created for the `final` version of the field:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before :: " + B.get());
        Field field = B.class.getDeclaredField("arr");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        System.out.println("Peek   :: " + ((String[]) field.get(null))[0]);
        brutallyHackYourWayThroughInternalClasses(field);

        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        field.set(null, new String[] { "Good bye, World!" });
        System.out.println("After  :: " + B.get());
    }

    private static void brutallyHackYourWayThroughInternalClasses(Field field)
        throws Exception
    {
        Field overrideFieldAccessorField = 
            Field.class.getDeclaredField("overrideFieldAccessor");
        overrideFieldAccessorField.setAccessible(true);
        Object overrideFieldAccessorValue = 
            overrideFieldAccessorField.get(field);

        Class<?> unsafeFieldAccessorImplClass = 
            Class.forName("sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl");
        Field isFinalField = 
            unsafeFieldAccessorImplClass.getDeclaredField("isFinal");
        isFinalField.setAccessible(true);
        isFinalField.set(overrideFieldAccessorValue, false);

        Class<?> unsafeQualifiedStaticFieldAccessorImplClass = 
            Class.forName("sun.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedStaticFieldAccessorImpl");
        Field isReadOnlyField = 
            unsafeQualifiedStaticFieldAccessorImplClass.getDeclaredField(
                "isReadOnly");
        isReadOnlyField.setAccessible(true);
        isReadOnlyField.set(overrideFieldAccessorValue, false);
    }
}

class B {
    private static final String[] arr = new String[] { "Hello, World!" };

    public static String get() {
        return arr[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks @Marco13! Works like a charm. I don't think I'll need the brutal hack for now ;-)